# In what contexts one says "but rather" instead of "but" alone?

Tags: phrase-usage, adverbs

I am not sure of the use of "but rather". For example, in this sentence

**The trigonometric functions are important in calculus, not so much because of ..., but rather because of the properties they possess as functions.**

If I am to write such a sentence, I think I may not say "rather" after "but". I would simply say "but because of the properties ....".

When to most appropriately say "but rather" is thus my question.

Answer (score 1):

The use of the adverb "rather"  after "but" is also correct. It has been used emphatically in the sense of "more accurately".